# Redirect all sub-domain directories to primary domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have 2 sites that were built on separate platforms. We closed one, which was located on the sub.domain.com, and want all traffic that ends up on that sub-domain to be redirected to domain.com.

I want all sub.domain.com/(anything) to be redirected to domain.com

I have only been able to make redirects that keep the directory.

I am able to edit .htaccess

Comment: Do you want sub.domain.com(/anything) to be redirected to domain.com/(anything) or do you literally want to just force the user to go to the front page and start over as the URL paths are too different?  either way, what redirect command have you tried and what happens versus what you expect/want to happen?  (Also... did you configure DNS so sub.domain.com points to the same IP as domain.com?)

Comment: @Foon I am looking for sub.domain.com(/anything) to go only to domain.com. They will be starting over. on the new domain. As of now, I have only set up redirects in cPanel, and this is only changing the domain, and not removing any sub-directories from the url. I have a cname record for "sub" on my primary domain pointing to @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.your\.domain$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is redirecting sub.domain.com to domain.com, but if I visit any sub-directory of sub.domain.com, for example, sub.domain.com/login.asp, I get domain.com/login.asp. Is there a way to get it to redirect to sub.domain.com(/anything) to just domain.com(index)?

Comment: Then replace `RewriteRule ...` above with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain [L]`

Comment: Perfect, that plus 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

to help with 404's worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. Definitely over my head with this.

I used

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.your\.domain$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain/ [L]
```

as well as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

To help with the breaking URLS, and for SEO